# Coefficients interpretation of survregbayes

Tags: r, survival, interpretation, spatial

I used the function `survregbayes` from the package `spBayesSurv` in R to perform a spatial accelerated failure time model with CAR frailties. The event I analyze is the digitalization of cities. The problem is that I don't understand how to interpret the coefficients of the model.
In particular, I get:

```r
Accelerated failure time model:
Call:
survregbayes(formula = Surv(t0, t2, treat_v) ~ total_pop_ln + 
    perc_over65 + Avg_income_ln + 
    software_ln + perc_graduate_employees + 
    frailtyprior("car", PRO_COM), data = df8_forsurv_non_2, survmodel = "AFT", 
    dist = "loglogistic", mcmc = mcmc, prior = prior, Proximity = queen.mat, 
    InitParamMCMC = T)

Posterior inference of regression coefficients
(Adaptive M-H acceptance rate: 0.1767):
                               Mean           Median         Std. Dev.      95%CI-Low      95%CI-Upp    
total_pop_ln                    0.0551136101   0.0550254170   0.0021825035   0.0509362581   0.0595294889
perc_over65                    -0.0040149026  -0.0040398522   0.0005232949  -0.0049687370  -0.0028849028
Avg_income_ln                  -0.0339629467  -0.0339211752   0.0164280091  -0.0630650276  -0.0034046992
software_ln                     0.0038724879   0.0038917297   0.0002729899   0.0033178749   0.0044044441
perc_graduate_employees        -0.0001839882  -0.0001824825   0.0001066416  -0.0003971492   0.0000258413

Posterior inference of conditional CAR frailty variance
          Mean      Median    Std. Dev.  95%CI-Low  95%CI-Upp
variance  0.004194  0.004148  0.000584   0.003124   0.005332 

Log pseudo marginal likelihood: LPML=-11671
Deviance Information Criterion: DIC=23500
Watanabe-Akaike information criterion: WAIC=23342
Number of subjects: n=56747
```

So, I have that the percentage of graduate employees does not have any effect on the digitalization of cities. For the variable software, the coefficient has a positive sign and it is statistically significant, so does it mean that higher expenses in software make the city experience the event sooner or later?